# R+ggplot: Heatmap. Specific color if value = 'X'

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

I am making some heatmaps in R with ggplot and using RColorBrewer. I have a range of integer values i'm plotting, but some of the values are 'None' and I'd like to colour these a specific colour. Can someone please advise on the most appropriate way to modify my code to add this functionality including adding a second legend that shows 'the new color labelling 'None'? I'm very new to R so not having much luck nutting this one out on my own.

Thanks alot!! :)

Example data

```
Target  A.tg_t0_rep_A   B.tg_t0_rep_B   C.tg_t0_rep_C   D.tg_t0_rep_D   E.tg_w2_rep_A   F.tg_w2_rep_B   G.tg_w2_rep_C   H.tg_w2_rep_D   I.tg_w4_rep_A   J.tg_w4_rep_B
1 : 12110501    None    0.5625  0.25    0.5714  None    None    0.5 None    None    0.2857
1 : 27262099    0.3333  0.8889  0.6667  0.9231  None    None    0.5556  0.6667  None    0.375
```

Code for plot

```
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)

data <- read.csv('test.csv', header =TRUE)
rownames(data)=data[,1]
data_shaped <- data.frame(sample = rep(colnames(data), each = nrow(data)),
                          dmr = rownames(data),
                          methylation_level = unlist(data))
# remove first n rows from dataset(first col header mistakenly being analysed)
data_shaped <- data_shaped[-c(1:2), ] 

# set colour palette
jBuPuFun <- colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(n = 9, "RdBu"))
paletteSize <- 256
jBuPuPalette <- jBuPuFun(paletteSize)

# heatmap!
ggplot(data_shaped, aes(x = sample, y = dmr, fill = methylation_level)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5)) +
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_gradient2(high = jBuPuPalette[1],
                       mid = jBuPuPalette[paletteSize/2],
                       low = jBuPuPalette[paletteSize],
                       midpoint = (max(data_shaped$methylation_level) +
                                     min(data_shaped$methylation_level)) / 2,
                       name = "methylation_level")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not quote sure how you have "None" in there mixed with numeric values. Are those being read in as factors? You probably want to set the "None" values to `NA` which is R's special missing value. You can do that during the `read.table` by setting `na.strings=c("","None")`.

But finally it appears that the `scale_fill_gradient2` function has a `na.value =` parameter. So if you convert your values to true `NA` values, then you can set a color for them just like you did for `high` and `mid` etc.

Example:

```
#sample data with missing values
dd<-data.frame(
    expand.grid(x=1:10, y=1:10),
    value=rpois(10*10, 10)
)
dd$value[c(5,10,55,77)] <- NA
```

now make a plot

```
ggplot(dd, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=value)) +
   geom_tile() +
   scale_fill_gradient2(high="red",mid="white",low="blue", 
       na.value="yellow", midpoint=mean(dd$value, na.rm=T)
)
```

[image: sample plot]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I can replace 'None' with 'NA' or NA or whatever is going to be handled by R the best. I have tried both and tried to implement the na.value option in scale_fill_gradient2 with a different colour pallete but it's not working. I don't get any errors, but the tiles corresponding to NA values are no different. Also, the scale has rise from 0>1 up to 0>25, so it looks like the NA values are being read in as a numerical values?

Comment: @user1995839 I've added sample data and code to make the plot. Maybe you can edit your original question to include the results of `str(data_shaped)` so we know the structure of your data. You want to make sure the numeric values are numeric.

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to help. You're a legend!! ^_^